# Android Key Board

Tags: android, keyboard

I am building an android application that supports only English. Say I have spanish Key board as default and access my app - It is not going to work. Is there a way I can suppress the spanish key board and bring in the English key board in my app.

Comment: I don't think you can force user to use specific keyboard, there is no attribute for that afaik http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12303593/change-keyboard-input-language

Comment: your can change your `Locale` inside `onResume()` and restore it to default **(Spanish  in your case)** in `onPause()` see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25524377/3193867) [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4985805/set-locale-programatically)  and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11036435/switch-android-keyboard-profile-programmatically)