# Android programmatically change language on rooted phone

Tags: android, locale, root, launcher

I know that there are a few question already answered on this topic but i have a more specific problem.
I have tried to implement [Android - change device system locale programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25355330/android-change-device-system-locale-programmatically) , with no success (simply it doesn't change the language, don't know if it's my implementation that faults...).

Searching i've found [Change Device language via ADB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21712205/change-device-language-via-adb), that is:

```
os.writeBytes("setprop persist.sys.language en; setprop persist.sys.country en; stop; sleep 5; start" + "\n");
```

and the same with

```
os.writeBytes("setprop persist.sys.language it; setprop persist.sys.country it; setprop ctl.restart zygote" + "\n")
```

that's work pretty well, apart from the fact that it does restart the phone (it doesn't reboot it, but it's a kind of restart).
I know that the "problem" is with the `stop; sleep; start` part, but keep them out return a change but not effective: system locale has been changed, but the effect will be shown only after phone reboot (i.e.: after reboot, language is changed).

It is really annoying to force the restart of the phone just because of changing the language; i know for sure that it is possible to make the changes effective (the default settings app does it), and i think (i'm not sure) that after making the language change a kind of intent is fired and all the apps check for the new language to show...

Does someone know how i could reach such a result?

I have a rooted phone so i have no problem with the permission stuff :)

thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm trying to going on with problem, i'll only share my last (failure) result... broadcast an     'android.intent.action.LOCALE_CHANGED' from the adb does not do the trick :|.... keep trying!