# I need to change the system language from my app installed as system app in Android

Tags: android, android-8.0-oreo

I need to change the language of the Operating system from my application (Installed as System app) and I am using reflection to get access to these classes

```
        public void setSystemLanguage (String langCode)
        {
            Locale loc;
            loc = Locale.forLanguageTag(langCode);
            try {
                Class<?> activityManagerNative = Class.forName("android.app.ActivityManagerNative");
                Object am = activityManagerNative.getMethod("getDefault", new Class[0]).invoke(activityManagerNative, new Object[0]);
                Object config = am.getClass().getMethod("getConfiguration", new Class[0]).invoke(am, new Object[0]);
                config.getClass().getDeclaredField("locale").set(config, loc);
                config.getClass().getDeclaredField("userSetLocale").setBoolean(config, true);
                am.getClass().getMethod("updateConfiguration", new Class[]{Configuration.class}).invoke(am, new Object[]{config});
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, Log.getStackTraceString(e));
            }
        }
```

My Issue is that `ActivityManagerNative`,`Locale.locale` and `ActivityManagerNative.updateConfiguration()` are deprecated.
I tried the following code

```
  Object objIActMag, objActMagNative;
        Class clzIActMag = Class.forName("android.app.IActivityManager");
        Class clzActMagNative = Class.forName("android.app.ActivityManager");
        Method getDefault = clzActMagNative.getDeclaredMethod("getService");
        objIActMag = getDefault.invoke(clzActMagNative);
        Method getConfiguration = clzIActMag.getDeclaredMethod("getConfiguration");
        Configuration config = (Configuration) getConfiguration.invoke(objIActMag);
        LocaleList localeList = new LocaleList(locale);
        config.setLocale(localeList.get(0));
        config.getClass().getDeclaredField("locale").set(config, locale);
        config.getClass().getDeclaredField("userSetLocale").setBoolean(config, true);

        Class[] clzParams = { Configuration.class };
        Method updateConfiguration = clzIActMag.getDeclaredMethod(
                "updateConfiguration", clzParams);
        updateConfiguration.invoke(clzIActMag,config);
        BackupManager.dataChanged("com.android.providers.settings");
```

My problem is that I cannot find a replacement for the deprecated method `updateConfiguration()`.I found a replacement for this  method

```
Configuration overrideConfiguration = getBaseContext().getResources().getConfiguration();
overrideConfiguration.setLocales(LocaleList);
Context context  = createConfigurationContext(overrideConfiguration);
Resources resources = context.getResources();
```

But I am unsure of how to use the context from here as I need to change the SYSTEM language. Please note that this  is not for changing the Application language.

The code to change the Locale in System from LocalePicker.java is

```
  public static void updateLocales(LocaleList locales) {
    try {
        final IActivityManager am = ActivityManager.getService();
        final Configuration config = am.getConfiguration();
        config.setLocales(locales);
        config.userSetLocale = true;

        am.updatePersistentConfiguration(config);        
        BackupManager.dataChanged("com.android.providers.settings");
    } catch (RemoteException e) {          
    }
}
```

Please find a replacement for the deprecated method `updateConfiguration()` so that I can Apply The changes to the SYSTEM

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/25355330/2550246

Comment: Please read the question before commenting.I have gone through these links and I could not find a solution. That is why I posted a question.

Comment: Always mention the API versions you are targeting and using to build your project.

Comment: Please refer to this and create a wrapper for the context object https://stackoverflow.com/a/40704077/2550246

Comment: Thanks. But this is not I need right now.I need to change language for the full system as I mentioned.Not just the app

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found another way to implement this without reflection.
Please understand this is only for system applications and for people who work in OS level.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ActivityManager;
import android.app.IActivityManager;
```

Method to change language. Must be a system Application.
with

```
android:sharedUserId="android.uid.system"
```

in manifest

```
 public void changeLanguageSettings(Locale language/*Locale.GERMAN*/) {
        try {
            IActivityManager am = ActivityManager.getService();
            Configuration config = am.getConfiguration();
            config.setLocale(language);
            config.userSetLocale = true;
            am.updatePersistentConfiguration(config);
            BackupManager.dataChanged("com.android.providers.settings");

            Log.d("changelanguage", "success!");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("changelanguage", "error-->", e);
        }
    }
```

Comment: How were you able to access ActivityManager.getService() without reflection? I'm currently using https://github.com/anggrayudi/android-hidden-api to access hidden/systemApi classes, but this does not make all hidden methods public.

Comment: I am currently in OS development so I can make my application a system application which can access the hidden classes.

Comment: I'm also working on a system app and it works fine on the device, but Android Studio still gives errors because it can't find the SystemAPI methods in the Android SDK. How did you get around that without reflection?

Comment: How are you planning to build your System app? We use a separate build machine and issue source,lunch commands and mm to make the apk. So I just code in the studio even if SystemAPI methods cannot be resolved and then copy the codes to the build machine to generate apk file.

Comment: @Phillen `getConfiguration` method is removed from recent android code do you know another way to get the configuration,https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/app/ActivityManager.java

Answer (score 0):

While i found no direct way to change the language of the device using code,
you could just use an Intent instead of doing all that implementation above.

```
startActivity(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCALE_SETTINGS));
```

this will display a list of the languages and you can just change it that way.

Answer (score -1):

Edit: This was tested Android M and havent been tested on latest versions.

Finally I have found it myself. Posting for others so they dont want to be in a mess.

```
    public void changeLanguageSettings(Context con, Locale language/*Locale.GERMAN*/) {
    try {

        Class<?> activityManagerNative = Class.forName("android.app.ActivityManager");
        Object am = activityManagerNative.getMethod("getService").invoke(activityManagerNative);
        Configuration config = (Configuration) am.getClass().getMethod("getConfiguration").invoke(am);

        config.setLocale(language);
        config.getClass().getDeclaredField("userSetLocale").setBoolean(config, true);
        am.getClass().getMethod("updatePersistentConfiguration", android.content.res.Configuration.class).invoke(am, config);
        BackupManager.dataChanged("com.android.providers.settings");

        Log.d("changelanguage", "success!");

    catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("changelanguage", "error-->", e);
    }
}
```

Comment: getService method is not found by ActivityManger Class @Phillen

Comment: as I said the log said that this method getService is not found. I've searched in andrid fragmework documention in ```http://androidxref.com/ ``` and you can see in this link ```http://androidxref.com/7.0.0_r1/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/app/ActivityManager.java```  that if you want to call getService method you must first call getDefault mehtod

Comment: this is for android 7.0.0.r1