# Change android system language by custom app

Tags: android, system

Is it possible to change android device language by custom app? Thank you for your answer beforehand.

I am creating android application. The app should change system language. I want to know that is possible or not

Comment: Not sure if this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25355330/android-change-device-system-locale-programmatically

Answer (score 0):

I also have to implement this into my App.

After a lot of digging i found this method to set the userSetLocale.

To use it you need to declare the WRITE_SETTINGS permission

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"
    tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />
```

You may also need the CHANGE_CONFIGURATION permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_CONFIGURATION"
    tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />
```

To grant WRITE_SETTINGS you can manually allow the app the permission or grant the appop via ADB

```
appops set PACKAGE_NAME android:write_settings allow
```

for CHANGE_CONFIGURATION you can also grant it via ADB

```
pm grant PACKAGE_NAME android.permission.CHANGE_CONFIGURATION
```

Now you can use this method to set the system locales

```
public static void setSystemLocale(ArrayList<Locale> languageList) throws ClassNotFoundException, NoSuchMethodException, InvocationTargetException, IllegalAccessException, NoSuchFieldException {
    //Tested on Android 12
    Class<?> clazz = Class.forName("android.app.ActivityManager");

    Method getServiceMethod = clazz.getMethod("getService", new Class[0]);
    getServiceMethod.setAccessible(true);
    Object service = getServiceMethod.invoke(clazz, new Object[0]);

    Method getConfigurationMethod = Class.forName("android.app.IActivityManager").getMethod("getConfiguration", new Class[0]);
    getConfigurationMethod.setAccessible(true);
    Configuration configuration = (Configuration) getConfigurationMethod.invoke(service, new Object[0]);

    configuration.getClass().getField("userSetLocale").setBoolean(configuration, true);
    configuration.setLocales(new LocaleList(languageList.toArray(new Locale[languageList.size()])));

    Method updateConfigurationMethod = Class.forName("android.app.IActivityManager").getMethod("updatePersistentConfiguration", new Class[]{Configuration.class});
    updateConfigurationMethod.setAccessible(true);
    updateConfigurationMethod.invoke(service, new Object[]{configuration});
}
```

You may have to use a different method for updating the configuration.
For my device (Android 12) updatePersistentConfiguration works. For older Android it is updateConfiguration.

[Here is the source code for IActivityManager](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/c80f952/core/java/android/app/IActivityManager.java#379)

Please keep in mind this method will most likely break in future releases of Android. I would only recommend using this for internal Apps.